# How to iterate through a string array and feed the datatable with the data given from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know what problem I have in my code , but I really don't know how to fix it. I'm stuck on this problem for hours...!

So, I need to iterate through a string array which have all the ID's that user selected in a previous page. I need to take those ID's and fill another gridview but I have no idea how to do that.

**Here's the code:**

```
string[] moodleIDs = this.moodleID.Split(',');
            ScheduleToMoodleTemplate s = new ScheduleToMoodleTemplate();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           
            foreach(var ids in moodleIDs)
            {
                dt = s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids);
     
            }

            gvEdit.DataSource = dt;
            gvEdit.DataBind();
```

In the above code I'm replacing the content of my DataTable each time round the loop. So when the loop ends it will contain just the information for the last id in the gridview, but I have no idea how to fix this...

Can someone help, please?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how it's done. After you create a new instance of DataTable, you should define its columns. Then, inside foreach loop you should create a Row every time. Row should contain data that match previously defined columns, so number of columns and type of columns. Then add that row to the DataTable, inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `dt` variable every time you do this:

```
dt = s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids);
```

I think you want to replace this line with:

```
dt.Merge(s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids));
```

This will append the returned result from `ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids)` to `dt` rather than overwriting it.

Comment: I had 4 hours trying to fix this and it was only a method called Merge , damn... I feel dumb! Anyways , thank you very much that's really it.